# Create a file after deploying file on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I have an app that I deploy to bluemix using IBM devops services. I am using Cloud Foundry as the deployer type and input from my SCM repository.

Everything works perfectly expect that I need to create a file called .env in my app's root directory after deployment.

In my deploy script I have tried all of these

```
touch app/.env
touch .env
touch home/vcap/app/.env
```

But nothing seems to be working. How can I go about creating this file after deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, another approach is to create an executable .sh script within a folder named [**.profile.d**](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#profiled) located at the root of your CloudFoundry Bluemix app files (presumably where your composer.json resides if this is Laravel composer based).  This will run for each and every app instance **prior** to application startup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any way to know the space in which I am deploying inside the shell script, like $HOME will give me home path is there any other variable that I have access to; which gives me the space of deployment ?

Comment: @PercyMamedy - Here's a handy web url ( http://env.mybluemix.net/ ) for seeing what types of info is available in the environment var context. The app is running most of the time.   You'll notice that your app's space context is located in a JSON dict named VCAP_APPLICATION within a key aptly named "space_name".  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Given you're creating the file *after* deployment you should be able to create it from your application itself.

Here's an example you could put in the top of your app.js (or server.js) file if you're using node.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('.env', data, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Created .env file');
});
```

------ edit -------

If the purpose of your .env file is to pass environment variables to your application then you have a number of ways of achieving this.

**Add environment variables to your app from the Bluemix UI**

- Click on your application to bring up the app dashboard
- Click environment variables (on the left)
- Click User-Defined
- Click Add

**Add environment variables to your app from the CLI**

```
cf set-env APP_NAME ENV_VAR_NAME ENV_VAR_VALUE
```

**Add a user provided service to store your environment variables**

You can create your own Bluemix service using the `cf cups` command e.g.:

```
cf create-user-provided-service SERVICE_INSTANCE -p '{"name":"value","name":"value"}'
```

You can then bind this service to the application using the `cf bind-service` command:

```
cf bind-service APP_NAME SERVICE_INSTANCE [-c PARAMETERS_AS_JSON]
```

Regardless of how you create the environment variables these will then be accessible inside your application from the `process.env.VCAP_SERVICES` variable.

[Further documentation](http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html)

Comment: Hii,

I am actually using PHP with Laravel framework for my application and my application will not run if this .env file is not present

Thus creating it from within the app is  not really adequate plus i do not want to run this code everytime I run my app

Any other suggesstions?

Comment: Can you explain why the file needs to be created after deployment rather than including it in the repo? What are the contents of the .env file?

Comment: The .env file contains environment configuration data like Database username and passwords, typically in laravel these data are not included in the repo because in this way every developer can have their own config for their localhost on their local repo and also your sensitive data are not exposed for everyone to see if your repo is public

Usually when deploying to prod on a laravel app you would create a .env for prod environment and include all the correct config info (eg Db username and password) for your production environment and upload it to your app via ftp or shell.

Comment: Answer updated to include new options. It's worth noting that these commands can also be run from your deployment script. For example you could do cf push followed by cf bind-service or cf set-env. (or both!)